# How does X11 xscreensaver know how long I've been idle (xprintidle unhelpful)

Tags: x11

If I do `xset dpms 600 3600 7200`, it blanks my screen after 10 
minutes of inactivity.

#### Questions

- How does X11 know how long I've been idle, and how can I access this 
  idle time programatically?
- I couldn't get `xprintidle` to install, perhaps because X11 no longer 
  has an XIDLE extension?

Googling suggested looking at "man xscreensaver", but I couldn't find 
anything useful there.

Answer (score 13):

[Screen saver](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/scrnsaverproto/saver.pdf) extension, QueryInfo request. If you are using xlib - its in [XScreenSaverQueryInfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xscreensaverqueryinfo) (link with Xss)

example in JavaScript, using [node-x11](http://github.com/sidorares/node-x11)

```
var x11 = require('x11');
x11.createClient(function(err, display) {
    var X = display.client;
    X.require('screen-saver', function(err, SS) {
        SS.QueryInfo(display.screen[0].root, function(err, info) {
            console.log('Idle time', info.idle);
        });
    });
    X.on('error', console.error);
});
```

example in c:

```
#include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    if (display != 0) {
      XScreenSaverInfo *info = XScreenSaverAllocInfo();
      XScreenSaverQueryInfo(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), info);
      if (info)
      {
        printf("%lu\n", info->idle);
        XFree(info);
        return 0;
      }
      return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to return -1 from main().
Better return values are EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE.